# Powershell import csv where column data matches data in txt file

Tags: powershell, csv, filter, txt, import-from-csv

I have a csv file that has header called CompanyName.
In the csv there are tons of rows and different company names.
But I keep a text file with specific companies whose data I need to retrieve.
Through PowerShell is there a way to make the Where-Object check through a txt file.
Something like:

```
Import-Csv -Path myCSV | Where-Object { $_.'CompanyName' -in names.txt}
```

The above doesn't actually work.
I even put the names from the text file into an array and tried checking like that but it also doesn't work.

```
$arr = [string[]]$arrayFromFile = Get-Content -Path "names.txt"
Import-Csv -Path myCSV | Where-Object {$_.'CompanyName' -in $arr  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked for me, just needed a small edit in the `Get-Content` part.

There's no need to convert to string array, but if you wanted to be specific about the type that's fine.

It should look like this-

```
[string[]]$arr = Get-Content -Path "names.txt"
```

Whole thing without the type conversion. You'll need names.txt and mycsv.csv in the folder, or to use the full path.

```
$arr = Get-Content -Path "names.txt"

Import-Csv -Path "myCSV.csv" | Where-Object {$_.CompanyName -in $arr  }
```

Comment: Thank you
Actually my code does work. Its just that the text in names.txt had whitespace at the end in each line. So after trimming it worked.